# How to inject context into custom function?

Tags: flutter

I am new to dart and flutter and trying to learn how to control the back button using WillPopScope.

My class looks like this:

```
class PlayPage extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Do you really want to leave?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('No'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context,false),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Yes'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ); 
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed, 
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar (
          title: Text('Play') 
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

My Problem:
If I take the code in the custom function _onBackPressed and assign it to onWillPop as an anonymous function, it works fine.  But if I try to call out to the custom function via onWillPop, VSCode highlights my context argument in my showDialog constructor because it doesn't recognize it being passed in and can't resolve it.  And I can't seem to figure out how to pass it in from the onWillPop call.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was pretty simple developer solution but I just hadn't thought of it.  Here is a solution.

In the onWillPop just use an anonymous function to call my custom class method and then just pass the context from there.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return _onBackPressed(context);
      }, 
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar (
          title: Text('Play') 
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```